# Encode subscription name with special characters

Tags: zuora

I am using the [SubscriptionsByKey](https://www.zuora.com/developer/api-references/api/operation/GET_SubscriptionsByKey/) API endpoint. It says I can specify subscription name/number.

I created a subscription with this name:

> foo, bar/baz

and this url would work: `v1/subscriptions/foo%2C%20bar%2Fbaz`

However if I add even more special characters, my current encoding mechanism would no longer be accepted by Zuora:

> AZ~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}|;:'",<.>/?

What would be the correct way to encode such subscription name?